# Swift, UitextField background with image on rightmost side

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have one UItextField and I want to show the date image inside a textfield in the rightmost side.

### Below is my code

```
txtEffectiveDate.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"sorting-selected-22pt" )) //  named: "sorting-selected-22pt")
```

But somehow it is not displaying in the UI page.

Let me know what i am Doing wrong?

Comment: try to set the txtEffectiveDate.rightViewMode

Comment: You have not set frame for the imageview

Comment: @k6sandeep ..how do i set frame for UIimage?

Comment: @Ramshad..i have tried to set ...but it is giving me compiler error

Comment: I have resolved it by using storyboard..